# is there any way to restrict out of stock products being added to shopping cart?

Tags: magento

Consider this situation where we have one product "Laptop adapter" and its stock as shown in admin panel is 10.

If a user selects this "Laptop adapter" and chooses quantity 20, Magento will give out a warning message like "Requested quantity for *** is not available" and adds this product count 20 to the shopping cart...

Is there any way to restrict out of stock count to be added in Shopping Cart, so the result of above example should be only an error message, without adding count 20 to the Cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to override and extend the Mage_Checkout_CartController with your own controller method and rewrite the addAction() to something similar

```
public function addAction(){
    if(items are out of stock condition){
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('your out of stock notice.'));
        $this->_goBack();
    }
    parent::addAction();
}
```

Comment: voting up is better than thanking then others can see if it actually worked for you and use the same thing if they need to

Comment: Anton this works when we add data manually.. but addAction is actually not called when products in cart are added to user cart when user logs in... i overrided addAction() and made it to exit on the first line, its clear that addAction is not called when cart is copied to user cart...

Comment: you did not specified this in your question but the solution is the same and you need to observe cart loading event or extend the method that gives the alert about "some items are not in stock"

Comment: sry for that Anton.. if so then i will dig into "Observing Cart loading event".. thank you for your initiation...

Answer (score 0):

In our 1.4.2 install, there is a setting in Admin so that customers cannot add out-of-stock items to the cart. We use this however, my Gal Friday does it, not me.